# jQuery plugin - image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, plugin, jquery-ui

This is my first jQuery plugin (used the jQuery ui widget factory). All code improvements are welcome.

[GitHub](https://github.com/Floris246/Teemr-Image-Slider/tree/6496c1c432b838f5dce92e97da50c6f76a465bee)

The plugin creates a gallery with one big picture and a given amount of clickable thumbnails. When the last thumbnail of set has been clicked it fades into the next thumbnail set.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

$.widget("company.imageSlider", {

    options: {
        debug: false,
        templateId: "",
        thumbAmount: 4,
        photos: [],
        imagePath: "./img/landscape/",
        thumbPath: "./img/thumbs/"
    },

    thumbSetPosition: {
        val: 0
    },

    thumbSetZindex: {
        val: 0
    },

    _create: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Create has been called");

        this.thumbSetPosition = 1;
        this.thumbSetZindex = 999;
        this.element.addClass("plugin-is-active");
    },

    _getPhotosByRange: function (from, to) {
        return this.options.photos.slice(from, to)
    },

    _getPhotoCount: function() {
        return this.options.photos.length;
    },

    _buildMainFrame: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Building main image frame");

        var widget = this;
        var container = $(".company-image-slider__main-image");

        // Add mouse over events
        container.on("mouseenter", function () {
            $(this).find(".company-image-slider__nav").fadeIn(500);
        }).on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).find(".company-image-slider__nav").fadeOut(500);
        });

        // Add on click event
        container.find(".company-image-slider__nav").on("click", function () {
            if ($(this).data("direction") == "next") {
                widget._nextImage();
            } else {
                widget._prevImage();
            }
        });
    },

    _nextImage: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Selecting next image");

        var activeImage = $(".company-image-slider__thumb-container").find(".is-active");
        var nextImage = activeImage.next();

        activeImage.removeClass("is-active");
        nextImage.addClass("is-active");

        if (nextImage.hasClass("is-last")) {
            nextImage.trigger("click", {widget: this, direction: "next"}, this._scrollToThumbSet);
            return false;
        }

        this._refreshMainFrame(activeImage.next().find("img"));
    },

    _prevImage: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Selecting previous image");

        var activeImage = $(".company-image-slider__thumb-container").find(".is-active");
        var prevImage = activeImage.prev();

        activeImage.removeClass("is-active");
        prevImage.addClass("is-active");

        // when the first image was auto-selected,
        // we need to go back as well.
        if (activeImage.hasClass("is-first")) {
            activeImage.trigger("click", {widget: this, direction: "prev"}, this._scrollToThumbSet);
            return false;
        }

        if (prevImage.hasClass("is-first")) {
            prevImage.trigger("click", {widget: this, direction: "prev"}, this._scrollToThumbSet);
            return false;
        }

        this._refreshMainFrame(activeImage.prev().find("img"));
    },

    _refreshMainFrame: function (image) {
        var currentImage = $('.company-image-slider__main-image').find("img");
        currentImage.attr("src", this.options.imagePath + image.data("origin"));
    },

    _buildThumbs: function (photos) {
        var widget = this;
        var options = this.options;
        options.debug == true && console.log("Building thumbnails");

        var template = $(options.templateId);
        template.addClass("is-loaded");

        var container = $(".company-image-slider__thumb-container");

        $.each(photos, function (i, photo) {

            var thumb;
            if (i == 0) {
                // clone the thumb-set container once
                thumb = template.clone();
            } else {
                thumb = template.find(".company-image-slider__thumb-container__thumb-set").clone();
            }

            var img = thumb.find( "img" );
            img.attr({src: options.thumbPath + photo.src, alt: photo.alt});
            img.attr("data-origin", photo.src);
            img.attr("data-index", i);

            // Add first and last classes to the thumbnail html
            i == 0 && thumb.find( ".company-image-slider__thumb--small" ).addClass( "is-active" ).addClass( "is-first" );
            i == options.thumbAmount - 1 && thumb.find( ".company-image-slider__thumb--small" ).addClass( "is-last" );

            if (i == 0) {
                // only apply the thumb-set container once
                thumb.find(".company-image-slider__thumb-container__thumb-set").css("z-index", widget.thumbSetZindex);
                widget.thumbSetZindex--;
                container.append($.trim(thumb.html()));
            } else {
                // place the thumbnail html inside the thumb-set container
                // and remove all the white spaces
                $( ".company-image-slider__thumb-container > .company-image-slider__thumb-container__thumb-set:last-child" ).append(
                    $.trim(thumb.html())).contents().filter(function () {
                        return this.nodeType === 3;
                    }).remove();
            }
        });

        // Add click events
        $( ".company-image-slider__thumb--small" ).on(
            "click", { widget: this }, this._handleThumbClick
        );

        $( ".company-image-slider__thumb--small.is-first" ).on(
            "click", { widget: this, direction: "prev" }, function (e) {
                widget._scrollToThumbSet(e);
                widget._clearThumbs();

            }
        );

        $( ".company-image-slider__thumb--small.is-last" ).on(
            "click", { widget: this, direction: "next" }, function (e) {
                widget._scrollToThumbSet(e);
                widget._clearThumbs();
            }
        );

        // Load remaining images message container
        widget._showRemainingImages($( ".company-image-slider__thumb--small.is-last" ));
    },

    _showRemainingImages: function(element) {
        var html =  $( "<div></div>" );
        html.addClass( "company-image-slider__message--block" );

        var i = $(element).find( "img" ).data( "index" ) + 1;
        var nextInLine = this._getPhotoCount() - i * this.thumbSetPosition;

        if(nextInLine > 0) {
            html.text( nextInLine + " more " );
            $(element).prepend( html );
            html.fadeIn( 500 );
        }
    },

    _scrollToThumbSet: function (e) {
        var widget = e.data.widget;
        widget.options.debug == true && console.log("Scrolling to next slides");

        if (e.data.direction == "next") {
            if (widget.thumbSetPosition < widget.options.photos.length / widget.options.thumbAmount) {
                widget.thumbSetPosition++;
            }
        } else {
            if (widget.thumbSetPosition > 1) {
                widget.thumbSetPosition--;
            }
        }

        var nextSetEnd = widget.thumbSetPosition * widget.options.thumbAmount;
        var nextSetStart = nextSetEnd - widget.options.thumbAmount;
        var photos = widget._getPhotosByRange(nextSetStart, nextSetEnd);

        widget._buildThumbs(photos);
    },

    _handleThumbClick: function (event) {
        event.data.widget.options.debug == true && console.log("Handling thumbnail click");

        $(this).siblings().removeClass("is-active");
        $(this).addClass("is-active");

        event.data.widget._refreshMainFrame($(this).find("img"));
    },

    _clearThumbs: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Clearing old thumbs nails");

        var oldContainer = $( ".company-image-slider__thumb-container > div:nth-child(3)" );
        oldContainer.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    },

    _destroy: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Destroy has been called");

        if (this.element.hasClass("plugin-is-active")) {
            this.element.removeClass("plugin-is-active");
        }
    },

    start: function () {
        this.options.debug == true && console.log("Plugin Company Image Slider running");

        this._buildMainFrame();

        var photos = this._getPhotosByRange(0, 4);
        var image = $( ".company-image-slider__main-image img" ).attr("src", photos[0].src).attr("alt", photos[0].alt).attr("data-origin", photos[0].src);

        this._refreshMainFrame(image);
        this._buildThumbs(photos);
        this._trigger("complete", null, {value: image});
    }
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, I would say the code is well written.  I can't speak about the jQueryUI parts because I am not as familiar with it.  However, there are a couple of things you can do to improve it though.  Most of these would be what I would call micro-optimizations.

First, you need to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code as much as possible.  For instance, you repeat this line a lot.

```
this.options.debug == true && console.log("Selecting previous image");
```

If you find you are repeating a line of code then it really should be a function. Also, there is no need to check for a value of `true`.

```
_log : function ( txt ) {
  this.options.debug && console.log( txt );
}
```

Another line that is used repeatedly is the one similar to below:

```
prevImage.trigger("click", {widget: this, direction: "prev"}, this._scrollToThumbSet);
```

Again, you can make a function out of this:

```
_triggerClick :  function ( el, dir, fn ) {
  el.trigger("click", {widget: this, direction: dir }, fn);
}

this._triggerClick( prevImage, "prev", this._scrollToThumbSet );
this._triggerClick( activeImage, "prev, this._scrollToThumbSet );
```

The other thing is you have some very long functions.  These should probably be broken up into smaller sub functions. For instance, your `_buldThumbs` is huge. just the `$.each` is over 20 lines long.

Also, you have `(i == 0)` checks three separate times in that function.  You should use `===` instead.  But there should be a way to simplify that code.

```
var isFirst = !!(!i); // !i is same as i===0 !! forces a boolean value

var thumb = ( isFirst ) ? template.clone() : template.find(".company-image-slider__thumb-container__thumb-set").clone();
```

You should also cache all of your selections that occur more once. You do this in most cases, but there are a few places you didn't.  In the `_handleThumbClick` function, you have `$(this)` twice.  Go ahead and set a variable:

```
var $t = $(this);
$t.siblings().removeClass("is-active");
$t.addClass("is-active");
```

Or just chain it together:

```
$(this).addClass("is-active").siblings().removeClass("is-active");
```

If all of your slideshow is inside of a single `div` container, you can do a selection on that container, cache it, and use it and `.find` to do all of your other selections.  This would improve jQuery's performance.

```
var $ss = $('.company-image-slider');  //or whatever
var thumbContainer = $ss.find('.company-image-slider__thumb-container');
//etc etc
```

Lastly, in your `destroy` function you check to see if the element has the class before you remove it. You can call `removeClass` either way.  If the class is there, it is removed; otherwise it does nothing.

I hope that helps.
Feel free to leave a comment if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you Gary. It's appreciated. I will use your comments to improve the code when I find time to do so.